# Making tags in Taxonomy-view appear dynamically?

Tags: views

### Background

I've created a Taxonomy-view that shows about 5 terms each time from a vocabulary of about **40** terms.

### My desire

I need that in every page refresh, 5 different tags will be shown Randomly/dynamic, and not the same tags that appear there time and again.

- I want to do it with the Views module itself, without further contribs.
- I don't want to customize anything manually, rather using only the UI.

### Clarification note

I'm not talking about random sorting of the existing 5 tags, rather I mean that each page refresh will bring different 5 tags, that are (generally) different from those in the previous refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Add Sort Criteria: Global: Random in view

[image]

Change the pager limit according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that and it sorts the same 5 terms in a different manner, instead of showing different 5 of the whole 40 terms vocabulary, so it's not the solution for me :|

Answer (score 0):

In response to your reply to Aldi, is global:random the only sort criteria you've chosen? And if not, is it at the top of the sort list?

I've no idea why Aldi's suggestion wouldn't work but without any coding, the easiest plan B would be to use global:random with a pager and use css to hide that specific pager.

Comment: Yes it was the only one, and the number of items to show was 5.

Comment: I checked a new view using global: random and a set number of results and it works fine.. When stuff like this happens, I just create a new view from scratch. Can you try that and if it doesn't work, post the export code for the view?